# my php form works but I dont receive any information filled in the form, just the subject

Tags: php, html

This is the php code, I am receiving email with subject only,there's no body or any information filled out in the form.

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Afriartstyle.com'; 
$to = 'Myemail@gmail.com '; 
$subject = 'Customer Inquiry';
$body ='From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message' ;

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .='From: from@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: reply@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This is the html code as you can see there is name,email and message, they are not appearing in the email

```
 <form id="main-contact-form" action="1.php" name="contact-form" method="POST" >
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" input name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea input name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Well the subject is appearing because you're hard-coding the subject variable in your PHP.

Comment: Also, your inputs are invalid. Why do you have `input` as an attribute on the elements?

Comment: I'd put print $_REQUEST on top of your PHP file and see which of your files are being posted to the script

Answer (score 0):

Try change this $body variable using single quote to double quote.
I hope that helps.

```
$body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n....";
```

and please dont use image for your code, hard for us to copy & paste.